# Are there good patterns for disposing view models when navigating back to a view?

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, dispose

In Silverlight for Windows Phone I have several view models that are disposable and perform necessary cleanup, like event unsubscribing from longer-living services, in Dispose().

When I navigate back in the view stack and the most recent view model have done its deed to completion, I need to call Dispose() on it.

What good patterns of doing this in a structured way are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a Blend Behavior or attached property that listens for the [Unloaded event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.unloaded%28v=VS.95%29.aspx), and then calls `Dispose()` on the `DataContext` of the object if it's `IDisposable`.  This could then be attached to your Views as appropriate.

Comment: It sounds useful, but I haven't really seen it elsewhere. Is this something you've tried yourself?

Comment: @JohannGerell Yes, I'm actually doing this now in one of my projects.  It works fine.  I needed this to force save/close calling on some ViewModels, and this works quite well.